# Download a zip file using Groovy

Tags: groovy, zip

I need to download a zip file from a url using groovy.

Test url: https://gist.github.com/daicham/5ac8461b8b49385244aa0977638c3420/archive/17a929502e6dda24d0ecfd5bb816c78a2bd5a088.zip

What I've done so far:

```
def static downloadArtifacts(url,filename) {
        new URL(url).openConnection().with { conn ->
            conn.setRequestProperty("PRIVATE-TOKEN", "xxxx")
            url = conn.getHeaderField( "Location" )
            if( !url ) {
                new File((String)filename ).withOutputStream { out ->
                    conn.inputStream.with { inp ->
                        out << inp
                        inp.close()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But while opening the downloaded zip file I get an error "An error occurred while loading the archive".

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your code hast strange lines, but works fine. i got zip file with `.gitlab-ci.yml` in it.

Comment: View the file in a text editor (Notepad, TextEdit, vi) and see what the contents are.  If it's binary that's not going to do much for you, but odds are it's a text representation of an error that you got while downloading the file.  It may point you to what you can change, especially since @daggett was able to get a file successfully with your code.

Comment: @Daniel I found out that it was an issue with the actual url I was using. I corrected the url and now it works. Thanks for the pointer to open the file in an editor. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
URL url2download = new URL(url)
File file = new File(filename)
file.bytes = url2download.bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with HttpBuilder-NG:

```
// https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/
@Grab('io.github.http-builder-ng:http-builder-ng-core:1.0.3')

import groovyx.net.http.HttpBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.optional.Download

def target = 'https://gist.github.com/daicham/5ac8461b8b49385244aa0977638c3420/archive/17a929502e6dda24d0ecfd5bb816c78a2bd5a088.zip'

File file = HttpBuilder.configure {
    request.uri = target
}.get {
    Download.toFile(delegate, new File('a.zip'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it: 
    
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry
    import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream
    class SampleZipController {
        def index() { }
        def downloadSampleZip() {
            response.setContentType('APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM')
            response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'Attachment;Filename="example.zip"')
            ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(response.outputStream);
            def file1Entry = new ZipEntry('first_file.txt');
            zip.putNextEntry(file1Entry);
            zip.write("This is the content of the first file".bytes);
            def file2Entry = new ZipEntry('second_file.txt');
            zip.putNextEntry(file2Entry);
            zip.write("This is the content of the second file".bytes);
            zip.close();
        }
    }
```